# Does Spark List honour the IDropInItemRenderer interfaces?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

It appears as though the new spark List component does not honour the `IDropInItemRenderer` interface.

Ie - if I implement `IDropInItemRenderer` on my renderer, the setter of `listData` is never called.

Am I missing something, or is this interface now deprecated?

If so, What is the suggested approach for providing similar dataProvider context information to the renderer?

For example, I want the renderer for the last item in a collection to behave slightly differently.

I see that `IItemRenderer` now defines a `listIndex` property, however this approach doesn't work without knowing the count of the source dataProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workaround I've ended up using.

In it's own way, the `DataGroup` is dripping Spark's compositional goodness, in that it exposes a `rendererUpdateDelegate` property, which you can set with your own class to provide whatever custom functionliaty you're after.

While it's frustrating that the interface got dropped without really being advertised, this approach is much more powerful.

Here's an example class.  In my example, I want the last renderer to have it's `collapsable` property set to `false`:

```
/**
 * Decorates another IItemRendererOwner (eg., a DataGroup) and augments the updateRenderer method
 * to set the isCollapsable property */
public class ThreadMessageRendererUpdateDelegate implements IItemRendererOwner
{
    private var _dataGroup:DataGroup;

    public function get dataGroup():DataGroup
    {
        return _dataGroup;
    }

    public function set dataGroup(value:DataGroup):void
    {
        _dataGroup = value;
        if (dataGroup)
        {
            dataGroup.rendererUpdateDelegate = this;
        }
    }


    public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection;

    public function ThreadMessageRendererUpdateDelegate(owner:DataGroup=null)
    {
        this.dataGroup = owner;
    }

    public function itemToLabel(item:Object):String
    {
        return dataGroup.itemToLabel(item);
    }

    public function updateRenderer(renderer:IVisualElement, itemIndex:int, data:Object):void
    {
        dataGroup.updateRenderer(renderer,itemIndex,data);
        if (renderer is ThreadMessageRenderer)
        {
            ThreadMessageRenderer(renderer).collapsable = itemIndex < dataProvider.length - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's it's example usage:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <viewer:ThreadMessageRendererUpdateDelegate dataProvider="{dataProvider}" dataGroup="{threadList}" />
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
    <s:DataGroup height="100%"
                 width="100%"
                 dataProvider="{dataProvider}"
                 itemRenderer="ThreadMessageRenderer"
                 id="threadList"
                 >
    </s:DataGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man! Just spent ages trying to find `DataGroup.rendererUpdateDelegate(...)`, eventually discovering why I couldn't, courtesy of this SO post.

Anyway, thinking about the (disappearance of) `rendererUpdateDelegate` property and your offering a little bit more, I realise neither are really necessary.

`DataGroup` has the `rendererAdd` event which gives you enough info, at the right time, to do what you want; for example:

```
...

<s:DataGroup id="dg"
    dataProvider="{model.dataProvider}"
    itemRenderer="{model.itemRendererFactory}"
    rendererAdd="model.updateRenderer(event.data, event.index, event.renderer)">

...
```

...and in the `model` we have:

```
public function updateRenderer(data:Object, index:int, renderer:IVisualElement):void
{
    if (renderer is ICollapsable)
    {
        ICollapsable(renderer).collapse = index < dataProvider.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Fewer lines of code and clearer intent

Comment: I didn't think `rendererAdd` fired when a renderer was recycled, though I could be wrong.

Comment: You could be right, not in a position to check right now so best to treat that as a caveat